# Use wpdb->prepare for `order by` column name

Tags: sql, wpdb

In my current plugin, I am picking up the `order by` column as user input. So I thought of using `wpdb->prepare` to escape it.

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select id from $wpdb->posts order by %s %s", $order_by_col, $order_by);
```

This is not working because it gets turned into

```
select id from wp_posts order by 'post_date' 'asc'
```

(Note the quotes)

So is there way to remove the quotes? Also is this a proper way to use $wpdb->prepare()? Should I manually escape it myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `prepare` for column names, and you can't really use it for the sort order either. `prepare` will always quote the string. You will need to swap in the values yourself. Rather than try to "sanitize" the data, I'd use a white-list approach.

```
$orderby = array(
  'date' => 'post_date',
  // etc
);
$sortorder = array(
  'asc' => 'ASC',
  'desc' => 'DESC',
);
$orderbycol = 'ID'; // just a default
if (isset($_GET['orderby'])
  && isset($allowed[$_GET['orderby']])) {
  $orderbycol = $allowed[$_GET['orderby']];
}
$order = 'ASC';
if (isset($_GET['order'])
  && isset($sortorder[$_GET['order']])) {
  $order = $sortorder[$_GET['order']];
} 

$sql = "Select id from $wpdb->posts order by $orderbycol $order";
echo $sql;
```

Though, I wonder why you are not using `WP_Query` for this.

Comment: The white-list approach is a good solution and thanks for that. The query I have in the question is just a sample. The one I am using in my code is really complex and went through the documentation of `WP_Query` and figured out there is no way to do what I want without a custom query.

Comment: Would `sanitize_text_field()` do enough to keep the data safe?

Answer (score 4):

## As of Mar 29, 2023:

As of [milestone 6.2](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/milestone/6.2), which was released Mar 29, you can now use `%i` instead of `%s` as a placeholder inside `$wpdb-prepare()` statements for table and column names. Here's a [dev-note](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/08/escaping-table-and-field-names-with-wpdbprepare-in-wordpress-6-1/) about it with examples.

Comment: The WPCS though still have this as unsupported, "Unsupported placeholder used in $wpdb->prepare(). Found: "%i" (WordPress.DB.PreparedSQLPlaceholders.UnsupportedPlaceholder)

Comment: @GeorgeP I'm not familiar with the WPCS. But `%i` as a placeholder is already supported in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) for `$wpdb->prepare()`. Perhaps you can let the WPCS know to update their standards?

Comment: yes [they know](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56091) and have [been working on it](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/pull/2072) for a year now. Hopefully it will be supported soon.

Answer (score 2):

Whitelisting is a good option for 'ASC' 'DESC', but for table names on your ORDERBY clause, WordPress has a built-in function just for you!

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_sql_orderby

`$order_by_col = sanitize_sql_orderby( $order_by_col );`